# SQL request execution take to much time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which take sometimes 15 sec, sometimes 1 min. 
Please, tell me how i can do my query lighter.

```
SELECT TOP 100
u.firstName, 
u.id as userID,
ueh.targetID, 
ueh.opened, 
ueh.emailID, 
u.phone,
u.gender
FROM dbo.Students u 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblEmailHistory ueh
ON ueh.studentID = u.ID
WHERE (CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day,6,ueh.sDate))=CONVERT(date,getdate()))
AND IsNull(u.firstName, '') != ''
AND IsNull(u.email, '')     != ''
AND IsNull(u.phone, '')     != ''
AND ueh.status = 'sent'
AND ueh.reject_reason = 'null'
AND ueh.targetID = 28
AND ueh.opened = 0
AND u.deleted = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ush.smsSendFullDate, ush.studentID FROM dbo.UsersSmsHistory ush WHERE u.id = ush.studentID AND DATEDIFF(DAY,ush.smsSendFullDate,GETDATE()) = 0)
```

Comment: Did you already check the execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query greatly simplified:

```
SELECT TOP 100 u.firstName, u.id as userID,
       ueh.targetID, ueh.opened, ueh.emailID, 
       u.phone, u.gender
FROM dbo.Students u INNER JOIN
     dbo.tblEmailHistory ueh
     ON ueh.studentID = u.ID
WHERE ueh.sDate >= cast(getdate() + 6 as date) AND
      ueh.sDate < csat(getdate() + 7 as date) AND
      u.firstName <> '' AND
      u.email <> '' AND
      u.phone <> '' AND
      ueh.status = 'sent' AND
      ueh.reject_reason = 'null' AND  -- sure you mean a string here?
      ueh.targetID = 28 AND
      ueh.opened = 0 AND
      u.deleted = 0 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT ush.smsSendFullDate, ush.studentID
                  FROM dbo.UsersSmsHistory ush
                  WHERE u.id = ush.studentID AND 
                        convert(date, ush.smsSendFullDate) = convert(date, GETDATE())
                 );
```

Note:  Comparisons to `NULL` are never true for almost all comparisons, so `ISNULL()`/`COALESCE()` is unnecessary.

Then start adding indexes.  I would recommend:

- `tblEmailHistory(targetid, status, opened, deleted, rejectreason, sdate)`
- `UsersSmsHistory(studentID, smsSendFullDate)`

I am guessing most students have names and phone numbers, so indexes on those columns would not help.

Comment: @EdwardGizbreht . . . Did you add the indexes?

Comment: It Works! Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't it be better to replace `convert(date, ush.smsSendFullDate = convert(date, GETDATE())` clause with the following `ush.smsSendFullDate >= convert(date, GETDATE()) AND ush.smsSendFullDate <= convert(date, GETDATE())`? That way `ush.smsSendFullDate` index could be used.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas . . . SQL Server will use an index for the conversion of a `datetime` to a `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks okay with no redundant parts. The reason it takes a lot of time is because you are joining tables three times and there may be a lot of data in them. So instead of improving your query, try to improve the performance of the table by adding `index` to them on columns like `dbo.tblEmailHistory.studentID`, `dbo.Students.ID`, etc